# Automated Call Distributor

Tags: software-recommendation, phone

I am trying to help push linux into a small business. Proving to my boss that Ubuntu is fully capable the only thing that I am missing is an ACD phone system. Wine is particularly difficult to work with and I cannot get it to emulate our windows program at all. the system we use currently is oaisys phone system any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org)?

Answer (score 1):

[Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org) should be able to provide that functionality.

As a matter of fact take a look at this link: http://www.asterisk.org/applications/acd